# Trouble with Fancybox and Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, fancybox

I have a trouble with Codeigniter and Fancybox.
I'd just like to dynamicly change the content of my Fancybox by using ajax.

Here's my link calling my controller :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="<?php echo site_url('pages/get_info');?>" title="John Doe">John Doe</a>
```

My function in the controller :

```
public function get_info() {

        $str = '';
        $str .= '<section>';
        $str .= '<p>Pellentesque et arcu adipiscing, fermentum dui ut, interdum erat. Maecenas iaculis fermentum pellentesque. Integer nec auctor ipsum, quis sagittis nisl. Praesent semper vulputate ligula, eget commodo risus posuere vitae. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean hendrerit augue auctor purus facilisis vehicula. Suspendisse ligula nibh, vestibulum id eros vel, volutpat sollicitudin tellus. Nunc ac feugiat velit, a lobortis erat.</p>';
        $str .= '</section>';

        echo $str;       
}
```

... and the JS :

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

If I directly go to the URL returned by site_url('pages/get_info'), everything is fine ! The text is displayed.

Unfortunately, when I click on the link, the Fancybox appears but always displays "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

Here's my configuration :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.mydomain.com/mysite/';
$config['base_name'] = '';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Can someone can give me a hand or just explain to me what I am doing wrong? It would be much appreciated! Thank you very much!

### EDIT

Sorry! It was a stupid mistake with my $config['base_url']

Answer (score 1):

try to use something like that may be it helps

```
<a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="<?php echo site_url('pages/get_info');?>">Ajax</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

and read the example url here

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: I finally found it! It was a stupid mistake with my $config['base_url']. But thank you for your answer anyway!